# How is possible to give only one type parameter in std::chrono::duraction_cast while the template has 3?

Tags: c++, std

When we use the std::chrono::duraction_cast we write something like this:

```
 auto int_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
```

we give only one type in the type parameters. But the definition of duration_cast is this:

```
template <class ToDuration, class Rep, class Period>
constexpr ToDuration duration_cast(const duration<Rep,Period>& d);
```

it has three parameters.

How is this possible?

Comment: The compiler can figure it out the proper template arguments itself : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

Comment: The function `duration_cast` has 3 template arguments. If you specify none of them, the compiler will attempt to figure them out via *template argument deduction*. However, you can specify the first template arguments, as you can see here. The remainder still undergo template argument deduction

Comment: The result of t2-t1 helps the compiler figure out Rep and Period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is based on the *"Template Arguments Type Deduction"*

**this is how it works**

usually we do:

```
auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// some operations
auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// then
auto diff = t2 - t1;
```

the type of t2, t1 is:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>
```

**std::chrono::time_point**, itself is a template class as follow:

```
template <typename Clock, typename Duration = typename Clock::duration> time_point;
```

In the type **std::chrono::time_point**, we define the operator- like follow:

```
template<class C, class D1, class D2>
    typename std::common_type<D1, D2>::type
    operator- (const time_point<C,D1>& pt_lhs, const timpe_point<C,D2>& pt_rhs);
```

which is a function that takes two

```
const time_point<C,D>&
```

and returns a variable of type:

```
std::common_type<D1, D2>::type
```

the common type between the two duration is a duration itself, i.e, **operator-** returns a variable of type

```
template <class Rep, class Period = std::ratio<1>> class duration;
```

thus the type of t2 - t1 is:

```
decltype(t2 - t1) = class duration <class Rep, class Period = std::ratio<1>> 
// <- pseudo code, you cannot write this in C++.
```

so, one of the template argument of the function

```
std::chrono::duration_cast<class ToDuration, class Rep, class Period>
```

is already defined by the default value

```
class Period = std::ratio<1>
```

the first argument of this function is defined by the parameter of the function itself:

```
class ToDuration = decltype(std::chrono::milliseconds);
```

we need to deduce the 2nd template argument of the function **duration_cast**, and we are done.

```
class Rep = decltype(?)
```

again we deduce it from the return type of the result coming from the **operator-** i.e

```
decltype(t2 -t1) = template <typename Rep?, class Period = std::ratio<1>>
```

if you check the documentation of the template class **duration** you will find the **class Rep** is implementation defined(relies on the implementer of the STL library .that is. WindowsOS, LinuxOs, MacOs...) and it's either an integer or a float (**arithmetic type**)

Done!!!

all the 3 template arguments are well known for the compiler now:

```
template <class ToDuration, class Rep, class Period>
        constexpr ToDuration duration_cast(const duration<Rep,Period>& d);
// with
// class ToDuration = std::chrono::milliseconds
// class Rep = arithmetic type relying on the implementation deduced from 
   the return value of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()
// class Period = std::ratio<1> by default and it can be something else
   like std::ratio<0.001> for exple
```

that's it, there is no magic behind it and never settle for this kind of answer : "IT'S COMPILER MAGIC" there is no such thing as MAGIC, even MAGIC could be explained scientifically. ;)

Good Luck.

Comment: So we have something like partial function application but at the type level. We can partially apply type values and the compiler will infer the rest for us. Very nice.

Comment: I'm thinking I'll never be smart enough for c++ :p